# Ubuntu 11.04 autotest + ZenTest + libnotify not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I dig google in autotest with notification of Rails and found out this instruction is useful ([http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2009/09/01/autotest-notifications-on-ubuntu-using-lib-notify/](http://www.screencast.com/t/MWCJGpksNw)), however while I followed up to do, the result is:

> /home/vlpeng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- test/unit/ui/console/testrunner (LoadError)

I did made installations as below three componants:

> Ruby-GTK+2 / Ruby-GNOME2 / ruby-libnotify

and

> Ruby-1.9.2-p180 / Rails 3.0.9

I tried to figure out which gem and compiler are not contained in my Ubuntu 11.04, I was confused and don't know what else I miss.
Here the completed error message and screencast, any suggestions and advice will be high appreciated.

[Screencast](http://www.screencast.com/t/MWCJGpksNw)

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. I believe it is happening because of the different gem version we have on our systems. As you can see the instruction dates back to 2009 and in RoR world that is like a decade ago, things move fast gems are updated constantly.

I was able to do the whole autotest, libnotify, ubuntu thing previously but I think the version of rubygems, autotest, zentest, redgreen etc should be kept consistent with the ones on the tutorial page. Here is the link to the instructions I used to make my autotest work the first time. http://automate-everything.com/2009/08/gnome-and-autospec-notifications/

Comment: Those instructions failed for me with "no such file to load -- test/unit/ui/console/testrunner (LoadError)". However, when I commented out the two 'require' lines like one of the comments suggested, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Louis

Got a better alternative to autotest, it's called infinity test, it is much easier to setup as well check it out here, https://github.com/tomas-stefano/infinity_test . For more details on how to set it up and customize it go here, https://github.com/tomas-stefano/infinity_test/wiki/Customize-Infinity-Test

I have followed the instructions and I have been able to successfully replace autotest with the notifications! Yay!

Hope this helps!